# Как программно свернуть клавиатуру?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Требуется после сохранения пользователем введенных данных в EditText свернуть клавиатуру за ненадобностью.

Как программно свернуть клавиатуру на устройстве?

**upd.** В моем случае `EditText` после сохранения данных (иконка "сохранить") сменяется (`.setVisibility(View.GONE)`) элементом `TextView`. При этом клавиатура остается развернутой.

В [решении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728830/190461) (от `Flippy`) подсвечивается `.getCurrentFocus()`. Видимо фокус после скрытия `EditText` отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void closeKeyboard(Context ctx){
    InputMethodManager imm= (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    View focused = ctx.getCurrentFocus();
    if(focused != null){
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focused.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS); 
    }
}
```

Comment: в моем случае всплыли некоторые нюансы. У меня EditText после сохранения данных (иконка "сохранить") сменяется (`.setVisibility(View.GONE)`) элементом TextView. При этом клавиатура остается развернутой. В Вашем решении подсвечивается `.getCurrentFocus()`. Видимо фокус после скрытия EditText отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло вот так

```
public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) {
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789187/5330439)

В параметры передал `getApplicationContext()` и `editText`.

Comment: Достаточно контекста активности